# Adding numpy arrays to cells of a pandas DataFrame depends on initialisation

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, slice

I was trying to add a list of numpy arrays as elements to the pandas DataFrame:

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCldw.png)

using:

```
df.loc[df['B']==4,'A'] = [np.array([5, 6, 7, 8]),np.array([2,3])]
```

Whether or not this is allowed seems to depend on how I initialise df:

[Testing two different initialisations of df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYA81.png)

Can someone explain to me what's going on?

Here's the code as text for everyone to try:

**The code that's not working**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'])
a = [1,2,0,4,5]
b = [3,4,4,7,3]

df['A'] = a
df['B'] = b

df.loc[df['B']==4,'A'] = [np.array([5, 6, 7, 8]),np.array([2,3])]
df
```

**The code that's working**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'])
a = [1,2,0,4,5]
b = [3,4,4,7,3]

for i in range(len(a)):
    df.loc[i,'A'] = a[i]
    df.loc[i,'B'] = b[i]

df.loc[df['B']==4,'A'] = [np.array([5, 6, 7, 8]),np.array([2,3])]
df
```

Comment: can you please post your df as code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a `Series` with the correct index:

```
m = df['B']==4

df.loc[m, 'A'] = pd.Series([np.array([5, 6, 7, 8]), np.array([2, 3])],
                           index=df.index[m])
```

Note that in a future version of pandas this might trigger an error since the original dtype for `A` is integer. You would first need to convert to object:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(object)

m = df['B']==4

df.loc[m, 'A'] = pd.Series([np.array([5, 6, 7, 8]), np.array([2, 3])],
                           index=df.index[m])
```

Output:

```
              A  B
0             1  3
1  [5, 6, 7, 8]  4
2        [2, 3]  4
3             4  7
4             5  3
```

###### why does the second approach work?

Not sure, most likely due to a peculiar internal state of the DataFrame (I suspect because it's initialized solely from a loop and an empty object DataFrame), but this is most likely not supposed to work and is very unstable.

For instance this would fail if you add another column (even object):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'])
a = [1,2,0,4,5]
b = [3,4,4,7,3]

df['C'] = 'X'  # we just add one extra column

for i in range(len(a)):
    df.loc[i,'A'] = a[i]
    df.loc[i,'B'] = b[i]

df.loc[df['B']==4,'A'] = [np.array([5, 6, 7, 8]), np.array([2, 3])]
# error
```

But creating the DataFrame from a single block object numpy array works:

```
a = [1,2,0,4,5]
b = [3,4,4,7,3]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[a, b].astype('object'), columns=['A','B'])
df.loc[df['B']==4, 'A'] = [np.array([5, 6, 7, 8]), np.array([2, 3])]
# no error
```

Comment: This does seem to work for the first case too, thank you. But why does the second code work as it is?

Comment: I suspect this is due to an internal state of the DataFrame, I don't think this is expected. I would consider this a non-reproducible behavior and certainly wouldn't rely on that (for example it fails if you don't assign `B` or if you add another column `df['C'] = 1` before the assignment). Using a `Series` in the right hand side is the correct way to perform this assignment.